# ¿Cómo hacer una consulta en SQL agrupada en un solo registro en MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Buenos Noches estoy sufriendo con una consulta que estoy implementando a mi sistema. Actualmente tengo las siguientes tablas:

Actividades: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tareas:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La tabla Tareas tiene el idactividad como foránea de la tabla Actividades.
Lo que quiero hacer es mostrar el porcentaje de las tareas de cada actividad.

Por ejemplo: la "Actividad 1" tiene "3 Tareas" las cuales están en estado Realizado por ende el avance de la Actividad sería 100%, si 1 tarea hubiera tenido el otro estado (Pendiente), la Actividad tendría un avance de 66.66 aprox.

Espero su apoyo. Gracias

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Podrías adjuntar la SQL?

Comment: Estoy un poco nublado con este ejercicio, cualquier apoyo será bienvenido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta de esta manera.

- Primero listamos todas las actividades
- unimos la tabla de actividades con la de tareas
- agrupamos por id de actividad
- contamos los  id de tareas, con esto tendremos la cantidad de tareas por actividad

---

```
SELECT 
T0.id AS 'ID actividad', 
COUNT(T1.id) AS 'Cantidad tareas x actividad'
FROM actividades T0 LEFT JOIN tareas T1 ON T0.id = T1.idactividad 
GROUP BY T0.id LIMIT 1

+--------------+-----------------------------+
| ID actividad | Cantidad tareas x actividad |
+--------------+-----------------------------+
|            1 |                           5 |
+--------------+-----------------------------+
```

Se agregan un select que busque la cantidad de tareas realizadas que tenga

```
SELECT 
T0.id AS 'ID actividad', 
COUNT(T1.id) AS 'Cantidad tareas x actividad', 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tareas T2 WHERE T2.idactividad = T0.id AND T2.hecho = 1) AS 'tareas hechas'
FROM actividades T0 LEFT JOIN tareas T1 ON T0.id = T1.idactividad 
GROUP BY T0.id

+--------------+-----------------------------+---------------+
| ID actividad | Cantidad tareas x actividad | tareas hechas |
+--------------+-----------------------------+---------------+
|            1 |                           5 |             2 |
|            2 |                           0 |             0 |
|            3 |                           0 |             0 |
|            4 |                           0 |             0 |
|            5 |                           0 |             0 |
+--------------+-----------------------------+---------------+
```

se hace una consulta y se hacen los calculos correspondientes de las

```
SELECT ID_actividad,Cantidad_tareas,tareas_hechas, CONCAT( FORMAT((100/Cantidad_tareas)*tareas_hechas,2),'%') AS '%' FROM (
SELECT 
T0.id AS ID_actividad, 
COUNT(T1.id) AS Cantidad_tareas, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tareas T2 WHERE T2.idactividad = T0.id AND T2.hecho = 1) AS tareas_hechas
FROM actividades T0 LEFT JOIN tareas T1 ON T0.id = T1.idactividad 
GROUP BY T0.id
) AS TBL LIMIT 1


+--------------+-----------------+---------------+--------+
| ID_actividad | Cantidad_tareas | tareas_hechas | %      |
+--------------+-----------------+---------------+--------+
|            1 |               5 |             2 | 40.00% |
+--------------+-----------------+---------------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Acabo de obtener el avance con esta sentencia:

```
select cast((100/count(id))*(count(case when estado="Realizado" then 1 end)) AS INT) as avance from tareas where idactividad in (select id from actividades where idproyecto=4) GROUP by idactividad
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero necesito de que muestren las actividades con sus respectivos avances:

Deseo obtener una vista así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ayuda por favor..